# Are the following two LTSPICE statements equivalent?

Tags: ltspice

.meas tran vin_pp pp V(Vin) from=1m to=4m

.meas tran vin_pp pp V(Vin) from 1m to 4m

When entering the statements in the dialog box, the equal sign is not used. I am also having trouble getting the measurements to work when I delay the saving data until 0.9m. But this may be due to other issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is, quite literally, a 1 minute job: fire up LTspice, place a voltage source with <kbd>V</kbd>, set it to `sin 0 1 1k` and simulate for `.tran 4m`. Use any of your `.meas` commands and see that they both work. Maybe you're relying on simply <kbd>R-Click</kbd>, instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R-Click</kbd>, for editing.

As for the delay, make sure that the timespan *after* the delay is added includes the time interval set by the `.meas` command. For example modifying the simulation card above to `.tran 0 4m 0.9m` will show a simulation timespan from `0` to `3.1m`, which means that the `.meas` command will fail since it expects the final time to be `4m`, which it never reaches.

There's one final catch: all the numeric values are treaded as `double` (or `float`), therefore be careful when using decimals. For example simulating with `.tran 3.3m` may not guarantee that a `.meas` script using `from 0 to 3.3m` will reach that time since it may be represented as `3.2999...m` internally.

Comment: the program is not working as expected.  Can you verify the meaning of:   .tran 0 {END_TIME} {DISCARD_TIME} 1e-7  END_TIME and DISCARD_TIME are params calculated by circuit dynamics with .param statements  The transient analysis executes as expected but the measurement script fails when DISCARD_TIME is not 0.

Comment: As an aside --- isnt float single precision and  double "double" precision. why wouldn't 3.3m in the tran statement have the same binary representation as 3.3m in the meas statement

Comment: @BHS Can you show a practical example with the numeric values for `.tran` and the `.meas` scripts which don't work? Too many times I have seen people pointing the finger only to find out that the usage was incorrect (the manual usually has the answers). As for the `double` or `float`, the data that is saved in the `.raw` file is `float`, unless `.opt numdgt=7` (or greater). The `.meas` scripts operate on the `.raw` file. And `3.3` is `3.29999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875` (`double`) or `3.2999999523162841796875` (`float`), while `.params` use `double`, so `float<double` here.

Comment: I agree about what you say regarding endpoints. But Referring to 0.9m in your statement above, 0.9m is the time that LTSPICE should start to save data so I would expect measurements to be able to be taken in the 0.9m to 4m interval excluding the endpoints, no? You say that data preserved in the 0 to 3.1m range

Comment: @BHS "*I would expect measurements to be able to be taken in the 0.9m to 4m interval*" -- that's not the correct assumption. If your simulation is `0...4m` and you specify `0.9m` as the starting point for saving the data, the resulting timescale will appear as `0...3.1m`, not `0.9m...4m`. You can easily see that in the `time` axis. So trying to measure beyond `3.1m` (while still accounting for `float`/`double` precision) will fail. Also, `0.9` is a little tricky: `0.90000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625` and `0.89999997615814208984375`.

Comment: Thank you for your time.  .tran takes t=0 to be the start of the simulation.  .meas takes t=0 to be the start of the saved data.  Also, your info on fliating point is spot on.

Comment: @BHS Yes, that's what I've been trying to say. Glad it works.